# how to handle text and image input together in neural network algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I am working on neural network machine learning algorithm . i wanted to know input data formats applicable in NN feature list. is there possibility to handle text & image together as a input in CNN or using any other machine learning algorithm. how will i make sense of output.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to handle text and image data together.
The feature vectors created using each text data-point or image data-point can be combined together and used in parallel as a new big feature vector.
After vectorization of text data, there is not much difference between the pixel vectors and the text vectors.

Specifically in case of CNN, for the final model, a combined neural network can be created that has a convolutional branch one on side while the vectorized words branch on the other side.

[image: Here is an image that illustrates the same]

Image Credits: [This](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*oiLg3C3-7Ocklg9_xubRRw.jpeg) image from Christopher Bonnett's [article](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/classifying-e-commerce-products-based-on-images-and-text-14b3f98f899e)

For more details, please refer to above mentioned article. It has explained how e-commerce products can be classified into various category hierarchies using both image and text data.

Comment: thnx @Shashank_Dixena

Comment: Glad that it was helpful :) @androidraj